# Как ответить на сообщение бота в чате

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Всем привет!
Первый раз пишу бота Телеграм на python с помощью библиотеки aiogram. Хочу сделать простенького бота тех поддержки.

Условия:
Есть чат с юзерами и чат с тех поддержкой.
Бот добавлен в оба чата.

Логика:

1. Юзер отправляет сообщение в чат regexp='#вопрос' со своим сообщением.
2. Бот пересылает сообщение в чат поддержки.
3. Тех поддержка отвечает реплеем на сообщение от бота.
4. Бот пересылает сообщение от тех поддержки в чат с пользователями.

Я написал первых два шага и все отрабатывает как надо, но с последними двумя шагами возникли сложности, не могу понять как их описать.

```
bot = Bot(token=os.getenv('TOKEN'))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

client_chat = "" #чат клиентов
support = "" #чат поддержки


@dp.message_handler(regexp='#вопрос')
async def qu_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=support, text=message.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Без реплайса будет работать так:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.chat.id == client_chat)
async def echo_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.forward_message(chat_id=support, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.chat.id == support )
async def echo_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=client_chat, text=message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```